# can i use windows signtool on certificate created by openssl?

Tags: openssl, code-signing, signtool

I used openssl to created CSR and self-signed certificate (.crt). I took this certificate to use windows signtool, but I got the following error.
Can i use windows signtool on certificate created by openssl? Does the certificate needs to be pfx format in order to use signtool?

```
signtool.exe sign /v /f server.crt /fd SHA256 test.exe
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Please advise. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, you can use signtool with certs created by openssl.  And no, the cert does not necessarily have to be a pfx in order to use signtool.  Based on the filename alone, does the key usage of your server.crt permit code signing?  Typically, server certificates cannot be used for code signing purposes.  Plus, .crt files typically contain the public key only, not the private key; whereas, .pfx files should contain the private key, which you will need to sign code.  See the [command-line usage for signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) for more info.